# i want to execute another function in each database

Tags: database, spring, spring-boot, h2, jdbctemplate

I have a spring boot project using database(domain, jdbcTemplate, mysql)

but another project's members cannot connect my mysql database.

so i want to make embedded h2 database provided spring boot for another members just when we develop

but i met little problem is mysql's sql and h2 sql is different. we have to use csv data import sql.

mysql : LOAD DATA ......
h2 : INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM CSVREAD(csvfile)

if we make each method for mysql and h2, we have to change the code when we deploy.

is this any solution for solve this problem?

thanks :)

Comment: Use a persistence api like Hibernate to avoid such problems.

Comment: @rathna thanks your reply. i found some information for my project, and i decided my project is not suitable. reason is firstly i have to control a lot of data over 1M and i have to implement not suitable job for ORM likes create/drop the table and load data.. please advice to me, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Implement the database specific data loading into separate components that implement an interface and activate the components with a profile. So locally when developing say you will be running your app with "local" profile. Something like this:

```
public interface SpecialDataLoader {
  void loadData();
}

@Component
// no @Profile annotation, will be used by default
public class MySqlDataLoader implements SpecialDataLoader {
  @Override public void loadData() {
    // .. do it LOAD DATA way
  }
}

@Component
@Profile("local") // component will be used when "local" profile is active
public class H2DataLoader implements SpecialDataLoader {
  @Override public void loadData() {
    // .. do it INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM CSVREAD(csvfile) way
  }
}

@Component
public ClassThatUsesTheLoader {

  @Autowired SpecialDataLoader specialDataLoader; // the right component will be autowired depending on the profile here

  void useSpecialDataLoader() {
    specialDataLoader.loadData();
  }
}
```

Now when developing locally you can run your application with a command line parameter `--spring.profiles.active=local` and the `H2DataLoader` will be used. In production don't need to specify the profile at all and the `MySqlDataLoader` will be used.

Please read the [relevant documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) on profiles and how to use them.,